Do quantum entangled particle pairs actually interact?
I believe this question could help simplify the accepted understanding of quantum entanglement for myself and others with little to no real physics background.
So my understanding of one way to create entangled photons is basically the duplication of one photon into a pair with opposite spins. If that is the case, the superposition that describes the paired photons with opposite spins would have the particles at opposing vertical points on the wave function. So revealing, through measurement, what spin one of the photons is, isn’t communicating anything between the two particles, it simply necessitates that the other part of the pair, that has been opposite from the beginning, is still just that. Is my way of understanding here flawed or is there some type of interaction between the two particles that I’m missing?
Spooky action at a distance, only seems spooky to me if there is truly some kind of interaction going on. Instead of these photons just kind of humming along to the same tune.

It seems to me your understanding assumes there are what physicists call "hidden variables," i.e. that the two photons have a set spin from the time they are created. It's been (apparently) proven that this is not the case

I could be wrong, but I don’t believe a superposition exists when hidden variables are supposedly in play.

The spooky part of entanglement is the photon has no way of knowing what orientation in which we will choose to measure it.  Thus for the other photon there is no "has been opposite from the beginning," as you say, because the choice is not made until the moment of measurement.

Ah, that is much spookier.

You were right before conceding that this is spooky. Because the entangled particles indeed do not interact. Once you accept that systems can be in a superposition of measurable states, it immediately follows that they can be in a superposition of measurable states that have long range correlations.

@RC_23 If we black out a circular spot on a road with heavy traffic, it's true you can't really say with certainty whether there is a car or not in that spot, right? But if I black out a sphere in heavy EM activity, it doesn't seem clear to me that the boundary conditions may not be just so strict that only 1 possible solution exists to our blacked-out spot. In order to say that a measurement far away "changes" the contents of this blacked out spot, there needs to be proof too that such sudden arbitrary change is indeed possible, given how strict those Maxwellian rules are, do you think?

When photons are entangled, their properties (like spin) are correlated, not necessarily "opposite," but linked in a specific way. For example, if you measure one photon to have a certain spin, the other photon's spin will be determined to maintain that correlation, no matter the distance between them.
You're right that there's no direct "communication" between the particles after measurement. Instead, quantum mechanics says the particles exist in a superposition of possible states until one is measured. When you measure one, the entanglement ensures that the other particle’s state is instantly known. This isn't an interaction or signal traveling between them—it's a manifestation of the entangled state that was created when the pair was born.
The "spooky action" (as Einstein called it) refers to how this instant correlation seems to defy the idea of local interactions, but there's no faster-than-light communication; it's just how entanglement works in quantum mechanics.
So, the key idea: No hidden interaction happens between the photons after they're separated—it's all about the nature of the entangled state from the start.

Your view ("it's all about the nature of the entangled state from the start") is inconsistent with entanglement swapping. In experiments, entanglement is created between particles that have never interacted - nor have even existed within a common light cone. See for example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.3991 The authors state: "We ... demonstrate entanglement swapping between entangled photon pairs emitted from ... independent sources. The resulting correlations between particles that do not share any common past are strong enough to violate a ... CHSH inequality." It's quantum nonlocality.

Entaglement swapping is some more more magical actually. With swapping you can detect correlation if particles was entangled. And not found any correlation if they are not. So you can instantly detect that info on any distance. I don't know how explain that.

Entanglement swapping shows that particles without a shared history can become entangled, but this process relies on initial entangled pairs and joint measurements that establish correlations between them. Entanglement arises from the measurement linking the particles through their partners, consistent with quantum mechanics without implying nonlocal causation.  Entanglement swapping doesn't contradict the view that entanglement is rooted in the nature of the entangled states and the measurements performed.

Well, the problem is when you design an experiment in which two far away observers measure the two different spins, but  where each of the two far away observers decide randomly in which of two different directions to measure the spin.
In such a case there are correlations between the measurements that cannot be explained by a classical model in which you start with pairs of particles in different combination of spins in different directions. This is doable in the example you gave, which only measures one spin direction. In your example, initial pairs of particles with opposite spins are enough to explain the observations.
The more complex experiment that I mentioned, instead, introduce correlations between the measurements of the two particles that cannot be explained in that way, or in any classical local way. It can be explained in many different weird ways though, and one of them is that the particles are somehow connected, and the the angle in which we measure the spin of one of the particles, is enough information to use an algorithm that can generate these correlations.
This is generally not accepted because it would transfer information (not useful to us but enough to generate the correlations) at a speed faster than light. Some theories argue that they are connected by something similar to wormholes.
Physicists are not in consensus on how to interpret these results, I hope AI will help us find better ideas soon, perhaps a surprisingly simple explanation.

You haven't accurately described the problem with entanglement. Suppose you have two particles $S_1$ and $S_2$. For each particle you can measure two quantities $X$ and $Z$. The quantity $X$ has two possible measurement results $1$ and $-1$. The quantity $Z$ also has two possible measurement results $1$ and $-1$. We'll call the $X,Z$ for $S_1$ by the name $X_1,Z_1$ and the $X,Z$ for $S_2$ by the name $X_2,Z_2$.
In a suitable entangled state if Alice measures $X_1$ the probability of each possible outcome is $1/2$, and if Alice measures $Z_1$ the probability of each possible outcome is $1/2$. If Bob measures $X_2$ the probability of each possible outcome is $1/2$, and if Bob measures $Z_2$ the probability of each possible outcome is $1/2$.
The real problem comes up when you compare the measurement results. If Alice measures $X_1$ and Bob measures $X_2$ when the results are compared they will be found to be the same. If Alice measures $Z_1$ and Bob measures $Z_2$ when the results are compared they will be found to be the same. If Alice measures $Z_1$ and Bob measures $X_2$ when the results are compared they will match with a probability of 1/2: that is, if Alice gets $1$ when she measures $Z_1$ the comparison will find that $X_2$ has value $1$ with probability 1/2 and $-1$ with probability $1/2$. If Alice measures $X_1$ and Bob measures $Z_2$ when the results are compared they will match with a probability of 1/2.
So the issue is that the probability that the results will match depends on what measurement was done on each particle. Now, you write:

So revealing, through measurement, what spin one of the photons is, isn’t communicating anything between the two particles, it simply necessitates that the other part of the pair, that has been opposite from the beginning, is still just that.

But if this was the correct explanation how could the probability of a match depend on whether Alice and Bob happen to measure the same quantity on both systems?
The standard view is that you shouldn't ask for an explanation of entanglement correlations or anything else about quantum theory. This leads people to neglect even stating the problem clearly because that risks encroaching on the taboo against explanations of quantum theory.
I will give the only actual explanation of entanglement correlations I have found in the literature. Quantum equations of motion describe the evolution of measurable physical quantities in terms of matrices called observables whose eigenvalues are the possible measurement results. Large systems typically don't do weird quantum stuff because copying information out of a system suppresses interference - this is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
But decoherent systems are still governed by quantum theory and still have observables. Those observables can carry quantum information as long as that information doesn't change the probabilities of measurement results. In entanglement experiments the observables of "classical" systems, i.e. - decoherent systems, carry quantum information that gives rise to the relevant correlations by local interactions when measurement results are compared:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223
